# PayPal Questions Cost and API

Tags: paypal

I tried to contact PayPal directly, but they reply within 24 - 72 hours. I see that stackoverflow have PayPal board.

We are a company developing an eCommerce Platform that will be sold to our customers. According to PayPal, we will be the Partner and who we sell our product to will be the Merchant.

PayPal offer PayPal Website Payments Pro which currently cost £20. What I would like to find out will this be £20 per customer? Can this £20 be paid by us on behalf of our customer? If yes, we would like to do through code and not manually. How is this possible?

Comment: And how does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: PayPal has an API communicated through SOAP web service. So is relates to Java.

Comment: That's like saying PayPal uses servers to process the payments, therefore you should tag this with servers.

Comment: should remove server-side and java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each customer that is using the cart, would need to sign up for the service that it is designed to work with.  So if it is designed to work with the £20 service, then each of the merchants that will be using this cart will need to sign up for this.  What you may want to do is look into PayPal's Payflow Service for processing payments.  With this, you can be a reseller of the gateway, and then you pay for the service for your account and all of your merchants.  Then you would be responsible for billing your customers instead of PayPal, as PayPal will just be charging you.